# Google social Graph response decode

Tags: php, regex, social-networking, json

I would like make a script that automatically insert in a Array the Google+ ID's fetched from
the SocialGraphs Api but i can't understand the type of this result,here's the example of the result: http://pastebin.com/wfBAtjH7

If can be help,i've seen the method for isolate the ID's done in Javascript:

```
var oids = [];
var reobg = new RegExp("\\d{21}","g"); // only interested in user ID so prepare regexp
oids = resp.match(reobg); // get an array of ids
if (!oids == null){ // if something stringify it
   oids = oids.join(",");
}
```

For get in a variable all the text,i've used this code:

```
$gplus = file_get_contents('https://plus.google.com/u/0/_/socialgraph/lookup/visible/?o=[null,null,"103227580967788703328"]&rt=j');
```

Where 103227580967788703328 is an example Google Plus ID.

Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards.

Luca.

Comment: this looks like json... `print_r(json_decode($result))` this should show you how to access it. (if not paste the result to pastebin and give us the link.)

Comment: I've already tried with simply Json_decode but isn't pure Json.Posted the full link and method for get the result. Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and cycle through the input with this regex:

```
\[\[,,"(\d+)"\]
```

and grab the first group each time.

Comment: Is working very fine,i don't know how say thanks .Thanks you again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `\[(.*),(.*),"(.*)"\]` this is may help U.